# Disable special characters entry in tablet

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, tablet

I have implemented the below javascript method to restrict typing special characters except space, backspace, dot, hyphen and underscore but in a textbox and called this method in the onkeypress event of textbox.
The reason I have posted it here is it is working fine in laptop or pc but the validation is not working on tablet.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

```
function NoSpecialCharacters(evt) {
    //this method allows alphabets numbers and some special 
    //characters like space, backspace, dot, hyphen and underscore  
    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

    if ((keyCode >= 33 && keyCode <= 44) || keyCode == 47 || (keyCode >= 58 && keyCode <= 64) || 
              (keyCode >= 123 && keyCode <= 126) || (keyCode >= 91 && keyCode <= 94) || keyCode == 96) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: probably because of Virtual key board..You need to monitor for events when you press key in VKB.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you tell me how that can be done?

Comment: I am not sure of this...but can you check with `keydown` event handler instead of `keypress`. Also about monitoring events, you can check this link https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api

Comment: If I call the method in keydown event it is not working even in laptop

Comment: Works for me! Check this... http://jsfiddle.net/8x1e3skk/

Comment: If we remove the alert(keyCode) it is allowing special characters otherwise alert if fired soon after pressing shift

Comment: There is some conflict in keyCode value between keypress and keydown...i am looking into that...

Comment: `Updated` :-- http://jsfiddle.net/8x1e3skk/11/ . Can you do check with this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is working now. Actually the first method itself is working now. I think the issue was due to browser settings in tablet.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on how you achieved?..will help to understand me..

Comment: The method which i have posted in the question itself is working when I have checked it in other tablets and android mobiles. The earlier issue might be due to the settings in that tablet.

Comment: So have you yourself made some changes in settings..or it worked somehow..?

Comment: We have not done any changes but we have just checked in other tablets and since there is no error with the method we left it like that.

Comment: Ok..Anyways, Great that it worked... :)